# IPv6 loopback route getting hit

Tags: networking, routing, ipv6

[Topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvWRl.jpg)

1. Trying to ping 2001:db8:cafe:2::1:171(Host3) from Host1
2. ping6 from Host1 to Host2 works
3. ping6 from Host2 to Host3 works
4. on Host1 I have a route to Host2 as follows:

Destination ------------------Next hop ---------------------- Flag ---------------    If

2001:db8:cafe:2::/64 ---- 2001:db8:cafe::1:168-------- UG----------------eth0

5. On Host2 here are the routes

Destination ---------------Next hop ---------------------- Flag -----Use -------if

2001:db8:cafe:1::/64 --------- :: ------------------------- UG---------0----------eth0

2001:db8:cafe:2::/64 --------- :: ------------------------- UG---------0----------eth1

2001:db8:cafe:2::/64 ---- 2001:db8:cafe:2::1:171--- UG---------0----------eth1

0::/---------------------------:: -----------------------------------!n---------4401--------lo

6. tcpdump on eth0 of Host2 shows that the ping6 from Host1 with the destination of 2001:db8:cafe:2::1:171 is received.
7. The issue is instead of hitting the second or third route in (5) , the packets keeps hitting the 4th route. The packets are not seen on eth1 of Host 2. This loopback route got added by itself. I tried deleting this route but it keeps re-appearing.
   Any help will be greatly appreciated.
   Thanks

Comment: This can not work with the addresses you configured. The prefix `2001:db8` is for documentation only and is non routable. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3849

Comment: That is not correct. Those addresses are indeed for documentation, but they are perfectly routable in a lab.

Comment: @KevInski If you have reasons not to publish the real IP addresses you are working with it is perfectly valid to use `2001:db8::/32` addresses in questions you post online. It's a lot better to do that than to just use random addresses which may now or in the future be owned by somebody else. Of course any kind of obfuscation of data in a question has the potential to obscure the problem to the point where the question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your topology is incorrect. You are using the same prefix (2001:db8::/64) on multiple subnets. To get routing to work you have to use different prefixes. For example 2001:db8:cafe:1::/64 between hosts 1 and 2, and 2001:db8:cafe:2::/64 between hosts 2 and 3.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Okay I changed the subnets. Host1--Host2 subnet now is 2001:db8:cafe:1::/64 and Host2--Host3 subnet is 2001:db8:cafe:2::/64. I still dont see the packets  arriving on eth1 of Host2.

Comment: updated the question and topology after making the correction you suggested. But the issue is not resolved. The packets still hit the wrong route.

Comment: Your static route on Host2 (2001:db8:cafe:2::/64 via 2001:db8:cafe:2::1:171) is wrong. Remove that route and all should be fine.

Comment: And just to double-check my assumption: you *did* enable IPv6 forwarding on Host2, right?

Comment: Cool ! Realized i hadn't enabled IPv6 forwarding. Enabled it as : sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1 and the ping works ! Question: why in IPv6 we need to enable  forwarding where in IPv4 just adding a route works?

Comment: In IPv4 you also need to enable forwarding with net.ipv4.ip_forward=1. Maybe you already configured that in /etc/sysctl.conf?